# can i create ImageView programmatically before setcontentview android

Tags: java, android, constructor, instance, android-context

can i initialize ImageView or any other view programmatically before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in android??

actually i am getting an instance of a custom class (not activity)
before onCreate method globally
like this

```
MyInAppPurchaseBilling myInAppPurchaseBilling = new MyInAppPurchaseBilling(MenuClass.this);
```

and in that class constructor i have to use that context to initialize my preference class

```
public MyInAppPurchaseBilling(Activity launcher) {
        this.activity = launcher;
        tinyDB= new TinyDB(launcher);
    }
```

Here is my logcat of error that i am facing

```
07-05 17:22:01.852 9660-9660/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.write.urdu.poetry.urdutexteditor, PID: 9660
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.write.urdu.poetry.urdutexteditor/com.write.urdu.poetry.urdutexteditor.MenuClass}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:133)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:375)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:370)
    at com.write.urdu.poetry.urdutexteditor.TinyDB.<init>(TinyDB.java:55)
    at com.write.urdu.poetry.urdutexteditor.inapppurchase.MyInAppPurchaseBilling.<init>(MyInAppPurchaseBilling.java:48)
    at com.write.urdu.poetry.urdutexteditor.MenuClass.<init>(MenuClass.java:38)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: How is `ImageView` involved into the NPE caused by a null `Context`?

Comment: Imageview is just used as a example i already piece of codes that creating problem for me ..creating object of MyInAppPurchaseBilling class globally by calling its constructor and creating instance of my preference class (TinyDB) in that constructor..but i resolved problem by own soon i will update the answer that how i did i do it...thanks for quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my MenuClass Activity code i initialize TinyDB in MenuClass onCreate() method before setContentView() and did my work after getting saved boolean value from preference class

```
public class MenuClass extends Activity {

TinyDB tinyDB;    
    MyInAppPurchaseBilling myInAppPurchaseBilling = new MyInAppPurchaseBilling(MenuClass.this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myInAppPurchaseBilling.onCreate();

    tinyDB= new TinyDB(MenuClass.this);
        if (!tinyDB.getBoolean(Constant.isAdsDisabled)) {
//do your work
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_class);
   }
}
```

and this is the code of my MyInAppPurchaseBilling class i did nothing in its constructor but created separate method of onCreate just like activity's onCreate and initialize TinyDB in it and Called that onCreate method of this class in MenuClass onCreate after super.*** line...in this way i initialize TinyDB in MyInAppPurchaseBilling class successfully to put boolean value at start of app and get that boolean value in Menuclass afterward to further processing

```
      public class MyInAppPurchaseBilling {

            private TinyDB tinyDB;    
            Activity activity;

            public MyInAppPurchaseBilling(Activity launcher) {
                this.activity = launcher;
            }

            public void onCreate() {
                tinyDB= new TinyDB(activity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the `MyInAppPurchaseBilling` object created while still executing the constructor of the MenuClass.this object? In this case (and maybe until `onCreate()` is called on MenuClass.this, but i'm not sure about this) the context inside the Activity object (in this case said MenuClass.this) is not set yet.

Comment: yes you got my point, i already solved my problem by same thinking, yes MyInAppPurchaseBilling class object was creating successfully without any error but TinyDatabase Preference class instance inside that constructor was creating problem until MenuClass(which is Activity) onCreate() called so to check what i did for it check my complete answer

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is

```
   View view  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
    imageView  = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

    setContentView(view);
```

Comment: this may be its alternative but my question was different i said totally programmatically without using any xml file and inflate method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_main, null); // view Exists after this code
TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
setContentView(view);
t.setText("something");
```

here you can see `findViewById()` is called before `setContentView()`.  However the view exists because it is inflated but it might help you.